# sleep(1) + fflush(stdout) works via curl. NOT via web browser

Tags: c, cgi

the pauses (`sleep(1)`), work fine when script is ran via curl command
rather than run on a web browser.

but via web browser.. it will pause the sum of all pauses (3 x `sleep(1)`) and then  print them all at once

what can be done to ensure the web browser behaves like curl ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    printf("Content-type: text/plain\n\n");

    printf("%s\n", "test 1");
    fflush(stdout);

    sleep(1);

    printf("%s\n", "test 2");
    fflush(stdout);

    sleep(1);

    printf("%s\n", "test 3");
    fflush(stdout);

    sleep(1);

    printf("%s\n", "test 4");
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the *raw* response of your webserver (e.g. obtained with `curl -i --raw <url>`) please -- I suppose it might not use *chunked* transfer encoding automagically...

Comment: Enough for an answer I guess. There's not even a `Content-Length` header...

Comment: I'll explain the situation in an answer. BTW, you should add the formatted raw response to your question, it's relevant to your problem.

Comment: Looks strongly like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) or like some musunderstanding about HTTP. Please **edit your question** to motivate it and explain the overall goal

Comment: HTTP is not an interactive protocol. CGI is not an interactive protocol. In general when you make a HTTP request the only thing everyone is worried about is that you get all your data, not that it is reproduced at the same pace as your CGI script produces it.

Comment: @DeepImagination: your understanding of HTTP is very wrong. Take a few days to read more about it. You can find entire books dedicated to HTTP protocol

Comment: Without additional explanation and motivation, your question is not clear enough

Comment: @DeepImagination this *should* work with chunked transfer encoding, see my answer. But your idea of monitoring the logfile is very bad. Use some notification mechanism to know when the file was modified, e.g. [`inotify`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) if this is on Linux.

Comment: @DeepImagination another problem you will run into is that CGI scripts are normally restricted to a maximum running duration. You might want to use a library for creating your own HTTP service.

Comment: @DeepImagination: please **edit your question** don't comment it

Answer (score 2):

HTTP is originally designed to deliver a document. It has a header describing the document and the document itself follows in the body, normally all in one piece.

One of the headers is `Content-Length:`, containing the size of the body, so the client knows how much data to expect. A browser will typically attempt do fetch the whole document before starting to display it. As in your example, there's no `Content-Length:`, the browser just waits until the connection is closed.

Of course, setting `Content-Length:` will **not** help you here, the browser would still wait for the whole document. But there's also [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) for delivering a document in several pieces. You could implement it yourself, e.g. like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char buffer[1024];

    // note that "Content-Type" has an uppercase T, be exact when
    // implementing a protocol!
    printf("Content-Type: text/plain\n");
    printf("Transfer-Encoding: chunked\n\n");    

    // snprintf() just for demonstration, you might need it for output
    // of anything more complex than just fixed strings.
    snprintf(buffer, 1024, "%s", "test 1");

    // size of next chunk:
    printf("%zx\n", strlen(buffer));

    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    fflush(stdout);
    sleep(1); // or something more sensible, like, actual work...

    // more data, finally indicate this was the last chunk:
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Some notes on the feasibility of this solution:

- With CGI, as shown here, there's normally a limit on the running duration of the "script". It might be possible to configure the webserver without a time limit, otherwise this will just run into a CGI timeout. A better solution is to write this as a self-hosted web service, see [Basile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44919792/2371524) for some links.
- The nice thing about this approach is that it doesn't require client-side code, so it will work with nearly any browser (chunked transfer support is very common). The downside is you might loose the TCP connection due to some environmental condition and the only way to recover is to manually reload the page. Therefore you *might* want to use javascript **if available** and go for WebSockets (preferable, see Basile's answer) or, if not available, perform [long polling](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-01-http-long-polling/).

Comment: I don't think that the chunked transfer approach would work in general. Consider the following case: the logged file on the server side stays unchanged for a long time (e.g. a few minutes). then the corresponding HTTP request would stay blocked (for a few minutes also). And the browser won't be happy (because of a timeout). I really think that for the OP's problem WebSockets are required (hence also HTML5 & AJAX) or at least some kind of "semi-busy" periodic polling in Javascript in the browser

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch it works, I even used it for a simple chat application in the past, long before Websockets were available. Browsers don't just close the connection on chunked transfer, no matter how long they have to wait. The only problem is a lost connection, requiring a manual reload or some client-side code detecting this (like *long polling*) (Well, the other is a CGI timeout, but that's not directly related to chunked transfer encoding)

Answer (score 1):

**[HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) is much more complex** than what you believe, and CGI is obsolete (with HTML5 & AJAX applications). Consider using some **HTTP server library like [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/)** (or make a [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI) application...) and/or some **HTTP client library like [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)**.

To make your thing work without any library (which IMHO is a mistake) you need to study more HTTP and add [more headers in your HTTP request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), notably `Host:`, and in the response: `Content-Length:`, `Connection: close`

I strongly recommend not coding all your HTTP protocol handling by yourself (so **use an HTTP library**).

> what can be done to ensure the web browser behaves like curl ?

Nothing can be done; a browser is entitled to handle only *complete* HTTP messages, and there are good reasons for that. In addition, most browsers would open *several connections* (simultaneously) to the *same* HTTP service.

If you need an apparently interactive behavior of a modern browser (that is a browser window which evolves visually with time), you should consider using techniques like [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (with [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5)) & [WebSockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), so program the browser using JavaScript (which might be generated on the server side). Read also about [single-page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Look into the [websocket example of libonion](https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion/blob/master/examples/websockets/websockets.c) (it probably is quite relevant for your needs). BTW such a WebSockets & AJAX & HTML5 based approach has (over the [answer provided by Felix Palmen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44919926/841108)) the advantage to enable some more visually fancy thing (e.g. counting and displaying line numbers), and also (with some extra Javascript code) to add the ability to clear the shown log lines (on the browser side only).

BTW, on Linux specifically (with a local file system like `ext4`) you may want to use [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities to be notified of a file change. You'll want some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (or the older [select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) ...), but most HTTP related libraries provide one.

It is important to understand that **HTTP is *not* an interactive protocol** (every request is browser initiated and gets exactly one response). To add interactivity (flowing to the server) you need more (e.g. WebSockets, which provides *asynchronous* messages from server to browser), or at least some "semi-busy polling" that is periodic Javascript (in the browser) doing AJAX requests.

Comment: I think your response is a bit overkill, and there's already a shift away from (pure) SPAs btw, as Javascript will always be unreliable. Big players like Amazon only use it optionally. For the simple usecase of the OP, I'd definitely go with chunked transfer encoding, just not with CGI of course, so I very much agree with you on using a library for an HTTP service.

Comment: On the other hand most "interactive" web apps (think of chatting application) do use both AJAX & WebSocket

Comment: If it's "mission critical", there's always a fallback, and there's a school of thought for web applications (I forgot its catchy name) to start out with the minimum technical requirements (like, make it work in lynx ;) ) and add features as they're detected.

Comment: He did not really explain what he wants. Indeed, he is monitoring some log file

Comment: @DeepImagination: But HTTP is not an interactive protocol, and it is *client* (that is *browser*) initiated (with each HTTP request done by the browser expecting a single HTTP response in reasonable time). To send *asynchronous* messages from the server side, you need more (AJAX + WebSockets)

Comment: @DeepImagination as delays in a CGI script are a **bad** idea for virtually **any** CGI script, the question could use some explanation. The way it is now, it's not helpful for future readers.

Comment: @DeepImagination the most basic solution is described in my answer. It's been there for a **long** time, but isn't used quite often. It might suffer from lost connections, but it's the only solution working without client-side code.

Comment: @DeepImagination curl is NOT a webbrowser but a tool meant also for debugging web services, so it just displays what it receives. It's just not the way a webbrowser works!